# Windows App-specific dates and browser certificates

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, browser, certificate, date-time

In Windows 7 I can set a "per program" sound setting. It's cool, because I can mute the browser (by example) and listen music without a lot of "noise" from another open windows.

Now, I need a "per program" setting for date time. I need test some softwares in different timespans (some years ago; some years later, etc). But when I change the global date from Windows, I cannot browse the web because of certificate problems...

Someone knows some method to "per program" changing the date time?

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge there is no software or wrapper you can use to accomplish this. Your best bet to do this would be to use a virtual machine and turn on time synchronization. [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org) is a free virtualization program, but keep in mind you may need extra windows licenses.

Also, depending on your windows license for Windows 7 you may be able to use the [Windows Virtual PC](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/) and virtualize Windows 7 (I can't find it right now, but I think Ultimate/Enterprise allows you to virtualize it at least once.)